# Close script in R

Tags: memory

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
"Main.R"

for( i in ...){
...
...
source("file.R")
}
```

The problem is that when I'm running `Main.R`, It uses all memory RAM because `file.R` doesn't stop and it is creating a lot of them. (Sorry for my english).

So I get a message on Windows saying that memory couldn't read and write...

How can I fix this? Can I close ONLY `file.R` when it finishes?

PS:`file.R` call another scripts...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like you are executing source("file.R") as many times as iterations in your loop (extract it out of the loop). Plus use rm() to remove objects you don't need any more after you script has run ....

Comment: Yes I'm doing this, but I want this hahahaha. I have to execute file.R at least 25 times... I put rm() in file.R at the beginning but It doesn't work... Every script is on the task manager :(

Comment: Why not make it a function?

Comment: you need to indicate rm which objects you want  to remove, please see ?rm.

Comment: @tokiloutok I use `rm()` correctly because I put `rm(objects I want to remove)`and it doesn't work

Comment: file.R (and consors)  are probably doing too much ... have you considered using functions  instead as suggested by vaettchen ?  You could have a set of scripts with functions and deal with the execution code in your main.R. It could be easier to debug and to track which objects are created/deleted.  ...  but without more info, that's probably as far as i can go .  Check the Rstudio profiler : https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-with-RStudio as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using `pararell` so at the end of `file.R`I have written `stopCluster(cl)` and the task close after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gc()` during or after running of your function to release some memory. Also after `rm()` it may be useful.

Comment: Did you try to do it after X iterations? If you need at least 25, maybe every 5?

Comment: I put     `gc()` after     `source("file.R")` and in the loop and it doesn't work, still on the task manager a lot of Rscript.exe...